# Kendo UI Grid for Angular 2 edit row API issue

Tags: javascript, angular, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2

I have Kendo UI Angular 2 grid, and I want to edit, not entire row, but a cell on click. How can I perform that? 
In documentation [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/) described how to edit entire row. May be I can apply some directive to the cell. Like this way

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridDataResult" [skip]="skip" [pageSize]="pageSize" [scrollable]="scrollable" [rowHeight]="rowHeight" [height]="height"
    (pageChange)="pageChange($event)" 
    (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
    (edit)="editHandler($event)">
    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="columns" let-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="{{column.name}}" width="{{column.width}}" title = "{{column.title}}" editor ="{{column.editor}}">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                  <div kendoGridEditCommand>{{dataItem[column.name]}}</div>
              </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid>
```

But now I have buttons in all cells.

Comment: Looks like [`incell` editing](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/165) is on the roadmap for Autumn release

Comment: do you only want to edit a single column in each row?  then you can use the  [editable]="false" flag for the column. so you might have to manually define each column